# Modify module resolver when using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I want to avoid using relative pathing when importing other files. For example, I'd like to change something like:

`import InputBar from ../../pages/InputBar`
to
`import InputBar from components/pages/InputBar`

Normally I would modify the resolve options in webpack, but I'm using create-react-app and don't have access to it.

I would like to avoid using `npm run eject`. Is there another way to avoid using relative pathing for imports?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) which will give you access to configuring `react-scripts` to your liking and not having to eject from CRA.